# Why isn't my text animating with keyframes?

Tags: html, css, animation, text, css-animations

I'm trying to make my text go from left to right using keyframes, however it won't work, as in it just stays still. How can I fix this, any help is appreciated and thanks. Note: this is only a portion of the code from a larger piece.

Code:

```css
.text1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Power Green, Arial;
    .animation-name: lefttoright;
    animation-duration: 3s;

}

@keyframes lefttoright{
    from{
        left: 0px;
    }
    to{
        left: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text1">
    <h1>ABOUT</h1>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change `.animation-name` to `animation-name`

```css
.text1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Power Green, Arial;
    animation-name: lefttoright;
    animation-duration: 3s;

}

@keyframes lefttoright{
    from{
        left: 0px;
    }
    to{
        left: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text1">
    <h1>ABOUT</h1>  
</div>
```

Comment: -sigh- cant believe i missed that. Thank you so much.

Comment: you're welcome :)